# Did Yggdrasil players have an extradimensional space to use as an inventory?

Tags: overlord

Every MMO I have played gives the player an inventory to keep the items they find on themselves, however, I am not sure whether that was the case in Yggdrasil as it was a VRMMO which meant the players could actually carry the stuff they collected rather than having to stuff it somewhere. So did Yggdrasil players from Overlord have inventories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ainz at least has some kind of Inventory pocket dimension. Throughout the anime, he is seen pulling stuff out of thin air, like the potion for Enri, or the hourglass in his fight against Shalltear.